Why does Trump use "California" as though it carries negative connotations?
Trump says he’s ‘entitled to personal attacks’ as he hammers Harris on inflation with grocery props

"Kamala Harris is a radical California liberal who broke the economy, broke the border and broke the world, frankly," Trump told reporters.

Trump uses three adjectives here: 'radical', 'California[n]', and 'liberal'. I can see why the first carries negative connotations, and presumably the third as well if your audience is conservative. But why would being Californian carry negative connotations? Furthermore, if it does carry negative connotations, wouldn't that encourage "Calexit" sentiments?

I think this is a sociology or psychology rather than politics question. That a politician said it seems not very relevant. As a non-US-citizen, California has a positive connotation. Surfing, wine, sunshine, the ocean, Hollywood, who wouldn't like that.

Did you mean to ask why Trump is using that line of attack?  That's easily answerable.  That could even be extended to asking why Reps criticize that state.  Asking why California has a negative connotation presupposes that it indeed has a negative reputation, which is far from universally true.  Just like asking "Why does Texas have a negative connotation?" would be far from a given across Americans in general, though many Dems may make hay of criticizing Texas.  Not upvoting, downvoting, voting for closure, etc, just remarking why Q's phrasing seems to attract controversy.

Should I ask the second question (about Calexit) separately? None of the answers so far have addressed it.

As long as nobody addressed it, sure. Simply remove from here and ask separately. It shouldn't be too hypothetical though. Is Calexit really something that is significantly considered in California?

As "though it carries negative connotation" sounds a bit complicated. Trump uses the term pejoratively or derogatory.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Republicans use the term "liberal" pejoratively. Actual liberals are proud to be so. Everything is relative.

@Barmar But then the answer is becomes very simple. Trump uses Californians pejoratively because they aren't for him.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I try not to get into the mind of Trump. There be dragons there.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: for some def of CalExit it is actually [considered seriously]. But it's very difficult to find objective data how much of that is driven by a [counter-]reaction to the Republican phobia of CA.


Why does "Californian" carry negative connotations in the US?

I'm less sure about "Californian", but for California, there was recent poll about what drives the negative perceptions and with whom these find resonance:

Some of these attributes like "too expensive" don't easily translate into qualifiers about Californians, but some of the rest ("too Liberal", "not really American") probably do. Of course, if one listens to Fox News, many of those other attributes like "unsafe" and "in decline" are caused by the "too liberal" bit.
As an overall evaluation [of sorts] 67% of Republicans vs 13% of Democrats agree that California has been a "net negative" for the United States.

As discussed in an article from the newspaper (LA Times) that commissioned the poll, such polarization is strongly correlated with other political views.

I'm sure that economy wise, California has been a net positive for the United States. Anyway, in total, only 50% say too liberal in this poll, which is kind of equivalent of 50% saying not liberal enough? And only 29% saying un-American. Not sure this is enough for a negative connotation? And it's more sociology, the implication for politics is unclear. One might need to compare that with for example Texas as red state for example at the very least.

80% of Republicans are reported to think it is "too liberal" and that's Trump's audience.  Also there's this theory that constantly repeating a thing makes people start to think it's true regardless of whether it is or not so constantly hammering California as unamerican/radical/whatever creates its own myth.  I seem to remember Trump brushing off Clinton winning the popular vote in 2016 (when he wasn't denying it was true) by claiming if you ignored California she didn't win.  Why ignore California you might wonder?  If your supporters think it's not part of "real America" you can.

The obvious economic items - gas prices, housing, taxes, etc. are something that most people don't want.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution "California has been a net positive for the United States" Actual facts have little relationship to opinions. Remember, most Republicans think that crime has gotten worse during the Biden administration.

Specifically with K Harris, Trump probably wants to link her origins to some of the recent past's most ridiculous "woke" initiatives in San Francisco, like renaming a Lincoln high school.  Yes, that school board got booted, but still a line of attack Trump is keen on using.

California was the seat of the Beat counter-cultural movement in the 1950s, and the focus of the hippie movement and the Summer of Love in the 60s. San Francisco is generally considered a home for LGBTQ communities; Los Angeles is the heart of the movie industry, with its generally liberal class of actors; the state has always had a diverse population of ethnicities and races without the stigma of entrenched racism. And all the way back to the Gold Rush, California was viewed as an open, independent, socially-progressive, and somewhat hedonistic land of opportunity.
In short, California epitomizes many things that modern Conservative movements find objectionable, notwithstanding the fact that California has numerous strongly conservative areas.

It's also one of the leaders in the environmental movement, another progressive area. The auto industry hated having to meet their more stringent emissions controls.

@Barmar: Note that 15 other states have chosen to adopt California's emissions standards.  But California was the first, as a response to previously having a severe air pollution problem.

@dan04 That's what I meant by "leader". I remember in the 70's it was common to refer to cars meeting "California emissions standards"

Despite a lot of those items being positive, as well as good environmental initiatives, California is also chronically facing budget crisis, heavily over-regulated, starting with loos that San Francisco can't build and wanting to slap Cancer! warnings on everything under the sun.  +1, but it's not all just reactionary dinosaurs, there are some valid criticisms.

It's also home to Silicon Valley and the "big tech" companies, who Trump has accused of promoting liberal agendas and censoring right-wing voices, to the extent that he created Truth Social specifically to counter them.

The one piece that other answers are missing about California specifically, as opposed to other Democrat stronghold states, is that California has in recent years had significant emigration to other states, especially Republican states like Texas.  Without needing to get too deep into the specific policy failings that conservatives think California's voter base has voted for, the general sentiment is that (mostly rootless Metropolitan) people in California are voting for bad policy in California, then leaving when that policy inevitably makes their state bad to live in, and voting for the same policy in their new state.  While this quote from Sheriff Judd Grady in Florida isn't specifically about Californians it encapsulates the sentiment

But don't register to vote and vote the stupid way you did up north, you'll get what they got

So while there is Republican dislike for many Democrat policies, there is a belief that the policies California has specifically enacted are exceptionally bad for quality of life, since so many people are leaving to the states the conservatives live in which has consequences for the conservatives in those states.
It's worth noting this isn't the whole picture.  It's unlikely that the proportion of liberals in those emigrating is the same as the general makeup of California, that is there are likely a greater portion of emigrants that are conservatives fed up with California policy than liberals.  There is also a non-political issue that many emigrants have more money available due to California's generally higher cost of living and commensurate salaries, which has raised the cost of housing since they are willing to pay higher prices for houses which are still cheaper than they could get in California.

Using "Democrat" as an adjective is weaponized language.

Here's another good source on this: Neilsberg: California Population by Year

@SK I'll be careful to keep my adjectives pointed in a safe direction.

It doesn't carry negative connotations in the United States, rather it just it happens to be the largest state and a fairly liberal one. Because of this California tends to have an impact on the rest of the country with the policies it adapts which the Republican party doesn't like.
This tends to get it to be used by some politician's as an attack against people/policies that they don't like but that doesn't mean that there is a widespread negative view of the state.
Simply put it is the largest liberal state in the country and Trump is just using that to attack his opponents.

Not my DV, but isn't this answer self-contradictory? I mean sure, you can [implicitly] define GOP/Trumpists as non- or un-Americans, but isn't that similar mental gymnastics?

Regarding the 2nd para, do you have some polls/data that despite all the constant propaganda against the liberal states and cities that hasn't taken hold with a majority of the GOP, as a negative first thought when you name one of these, e.g. on an association test?

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Are you suggesting that those groups speak for America as a whole? No matter what you look at you will find that there are people who like it and people who don't that is just a fact of life. However that doesn't mean that as a whole something has a positive or negative connotation. In fact you will see Trump make such statements about any Liberal state that is opponent is from trying to suggest that the state is bad and un American.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever If I had polls/data I would have provided that but Trump does have a history of making stuff up at his rallies.
